# Writing to Firestore after logging out the Firebase authenticated user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In my app I use a simple logout method. This method deletes the current FCM token, clears the document folder on the device, and logs out the user. My authentication listener in SceneDelegate reacts to the logout and brings the user back to the login/register view controller. I would also like my app to update certain documents in Firestore (in this case the FCM Token array I store in the users document)

The problem I run into is, when I put Auth.auth().signOut() inside of the completion handler it takes too much time for the app to react, especially if there is bad or no internet connection. When I sign the user out first, the Firestore write fails because the user is no longer authenticated.

I've partially solved the problem with cloud functions, letting it do the cleanup in Firestore after. But I would like to do this using the device instead.

My questions are:

a) Is there a way to authenticate and start the Firestore write and logout the user in the meantime, not having to wait for the write to finish?

b) Is there a way to somehow cache this Firestore write until the phone is online again, even if the app has been closed in between?

```
func logoutUser() {

    InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID { error in
        if let error = error {
            os_log(.error, "%@", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()

        localStorage_Methods.clearLocalFiles()

        self.deleteAllFcmTokens() {
        ///completion handler
        }

    } catch let signOutError as NSError {
        os_log(.error, "%@", signOutError)
    }
}




func deleteFcmToken(passedOnMethod: @escaping () -> () ) {

    guard let currentUserA = K.Globals.currentUser else { return }

    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            os_log(.error, "%@", error.localizedDescription)
        } else if let result = result {
            self.db.collection(K.FStore.collectionOf_RegisteredUsers_Name).document(currentUserA.uid)
                .updateData([
                    K.FStore.Users.fcmTokens: FieldValue.arrayRemove([result.token])
                ]) { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        os_log(.error, "%@", error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        passedOnMethod()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My scene delegate:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let fb_Auth_Methods = FB_Auth_Methods()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in

            if user != nil {
                self.setAndGoToRootView(withIdentifier: K.ViewItems.mainNavigationViewController)
                K.Globals.currentUser = user

            } else {
                self.setAndGoToRootView(withIdentifier: K.ViewItems.rootNavigationController)
                K.Globals.currentUser = nil
                self.fb_Auth_Methods.detachTrackLoginStatusListener()
            }
        }

        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }


func setAndGoToRootView(withIdentifier: String) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: K.ViewItems.mainStoryboard, bundle: nil)
        var viewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
        viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: withIdentifier)
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to authenticate and start the Firestore write and logout the user in the meantime, not having to wait for the write to finish?*

Unforetunately no. Once you call the signOut() method, it invalidates your auth token. If the write operation reaches successfully before it can invalidate the token, then it may succeed. Otherwise it will fail.

> Is there a way to somehow cache this Firestore write until the phone is online again, even if the app has been closed in between?*

Firestore supports offline persistence by default, meaning all writes you perform (except for Transactions) will be cached and will get executed once you are connected to the internet.

It is generally a better practice anyways to do the cleanup in the back-end since the Firebase admin SDK bypasses security rules, you will be able to cleanup data that are otherwise inaccessible to your mobile clients.